# What's the best way to edit the look and feel of the dashboard

Tags: customization, themes, dashboard

I need advice if there's a best method in changing the look and feel of the existing dashboard. I've already mocked up the look and feel that I wanted.

I wanted a method where I can also let other user download this theme and install on their computer.

The obvious method I'll be doing is editing the existing assets from my ~/Library/Widgets/ but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it or there are other methods.

Thank You!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really an official way to theme widgets, or at least not an Apple-endorsed method for theming.

Editing the widgets is fine though, although be prepared that the system widgets in /Library/Widgets may get replaced on OS X updates, so keep backups and be prepared that things may change (they may rename the resource files, etc). Alternatively, copy the widgets out of that folder into your ~/Library/Widgets so that they are preserved on OS X updates.